# Non alpha numeric characters in Username in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I was successful in getting non alpha numeric characters in my Usernames, the problem I have now is when I try to assign roles to the users It is throwing an invalid username error. It says "can contain only letters and digits.

This is what I added to allow the characters in the username;

```
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        var userValidator = UserManager.UserValidator as   UserValidator<ApplicationUser>;
        userValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
    }
```

This is where I am getting the error;

```
public bool AddUserToRole(string userId, string roleName)
    {
        var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var idResult = um.AddToRole(userId, roleName);
        return idResult.Succeeded;
```

The idResult.Erorrs[0] = "**User name J.Blow is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.**"

Why am i getting this. Do I need to change the vaildation of the username somewhere else?

Thanks, in advance.

Clint

Comment: `um.UserValidator` needs to point to your `userValidator` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your code, you are creating a new instance of `UserManager` and using that in your `AddUserToRole` method. Therefore ignoring the `UserManager` you set up in your controller.

If you refactor your code so that you can use the one instantiated in your controller in your `AddUserToRole` method, that should work.

Comment: Another way to think of this.  Everytime you say new SomeClass, you create a new copy of it.  Making a change to one copy has no affect on the other.  You either need to add your validator to the code in your second snippet or pass the user manager that is injected into your controller back to your service layer (or whereever your second code block resides)

Comment: I just added the validator to the new code snippet to get it to work for now. Working with this Identity frame work is still a little grey for me. Thanks for your help.